# How to resolve Fortify Remediation Plugin issue having Read Time Out?

Tags: eclipse, fortify, socket-timeout-exception

I have installed redmediation plugin from ecplipse site :

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/fortify-remediation-plugin

While trying to connect to fortify server from plugin always getting the below error from plugin :

[image]

I tried increasing the timout properties but unable to resolve, also checked for any issues in the logs I do not have any other lead except below :

[image]

Comment: the plugin seems to be installable from that update site in general, so probably a network issue between your machine and that update site server. Maybe a proxy server in between? You could also contact the provider of that plugin and ask for a archived version of the update site, so that you could download, unpack, and install locally.